# Как посчитать самую длинную серию повторений в столбце SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Есть таблица такого формата

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как посчитать максимальную серию побед (самое длинно количество значений 1 подряд без прерываний) для каждой персоны?

Comment: Что задаёт именно такой порядок записей, какое выражение ORDER BY? физическое положение записи - не подходит. PS. Читать по теме "gaps and islands". PPS. MySQL <> SQL Server, укажите строго одну СУБД, включая точную версию.

Comment: ORDER BY person, EvenDatetime

Comment: В показанном наборе `person, EvenDatetime` совпадают во всех записях. Не подойдёт. ORDER BY должен обеспечивать уникальность каждой записи.

Comment: это лишь данные для примера, выборка отсортирована правильно. Тут сама загвоздка в определении промежутков где 1 идут подряд и выборе самого длинного промежутка

Comment: Публикуя примерные данные, получите приблизительный ответ. Не хотите работать над решением своей проблемы? ну так и мы не обязаны... PS. Пример данных надо давать не скриншотом, а текстовыми скриптами CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. И их надо сопровождать требуемым результатом для именно этих данных. *загвоздка в определении промежутков где 1 идут подряд и выборе самого длинного промежутка* Как называется эта, вполне стандартная, задача - я уже указал.

Comment: ну если бы например начиная с 20 записи person и date отличались бы то что это меняет? мысленно представим первый столбец id тогда мы прекрасно видим ORDER BY id

Comment: проще эту выборку передать в ваше приложение и там уже построчно пройтись считая единицы и сбрасывая на нулях

Answer (score 0):

попробовал решить для интереса. Как в комментариях указано, необходимо знать порядок сортировки записей представленных на скриншоте. Для примера добавил инкрементальный `id`.
реализация в ms sql 2012. Исходные:

```
declare @t table ( id int IDENTITY(1,1), person int, d date, v int);
insert into @t values 
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),--3
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),--2
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),--5
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),--6
(2, '2000-01-01', 1);--1
```

первым шагом `A` делаем выборку данных и вытаскиваем предыдущее, следующее значения и делаем нумерацию строк внутри групп.

```
with A as (
    SELECT * , lag(v, 1) over (partition by person, d order by id)    AS prev       
             , lead(v,1) over (partition by person, d order by id)    AS next
             , row_number() over( partition by person, d order by id) AS rn
    FROM @t
)
```

получаем результаты:

```
id          person      d          v           prev        next        rn
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
1           1           2000-01-01 1           NULL        1           1
2           1           2000-01-01 1           1           1           2
3           1           2000-01-01 1           1           0           3
4           1           2000-01-01 0           1           0           4
5           1           2000-01-01 0           0           1           5
6           1           2000-01-01 1           0           1           6
7           1           2000-01-01 1           1           1           7
8           1           2000-01-01 1           1           1           8
9           1           2000-01-01 1           1           1           9
10          1           2000-01-01 1           1           0           10
11          1           2000-01-01 0           1           0           11
12          1           2000-01-01 0           0           0           12
13          1           2000-01-01 0           0           0           13
14          1           2000-01-01 0           0           0           14
15          1           2000-01-01 0           0           0           15
16          1           2000-01-01 0           0           NULL        16
17          2           2000-01-01 1           NULL        NULL        1
```

далее (`B`) для строк, где `next = null` увеличиваем значение rn на 1, а также в выборке оставляем только строки, где сменилось значение `v <> prev` либо `next is null`

```
,B AS (
    SELECT id, person, d, v,prev, next
           , (case when next is null then rn + 1 else rn end) as rn         
    FROM A
    WHERE  next is null or v <> prev
    --order by id
)
```

получаем

```
id          person      d          v           prev        next        rn
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
4           1           2000-01-01 0           1           0           4
6           1           2000-01-01 1           0           1           6
11          1           2000-01-01 0           1           0           11
16          1           2000-01-01 0           0           NULL        17
17          2           2000-01-01 1           NULL        NULL        2
```

для полученных строк считаем (`C`) разность между текущим и предыдущим значением номера строки - `rn`, то фактическое число последовательных строк с 0 или 1.

```
, C as (
    SELECT *, rn - lag(rn,1, 1) over (partition by person,d order by id) AS cnt
    FROM B
)
```

на выходе

```
id          person      d          v           prev        next        rn       cnt
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ---------- --------- -------
4           1           2000-01-01 0           1           0           4         3
6           1           2000-01-01 1           0           1           6         2
11          1           2000-01-01 0           1           0           11        5
16          1           2000-01-01 0           0           NULL        17        6
17          2           2000-01-01 1           NULL        NULL        2         1
```

заключительным шагом делаем обычную группировку по персоне и дате, выбирая максимальные значения. но с условием, что `prev` значение = 1, либо если оно отсутствует, то `v`.

```
SELECT person, d, max(cnt) AS cnt
FROM C
GROUP BY person, d, v,prev 
HAVING ISNULL(prev, v) = 1
```

что вроде как дает искомые значения

```
person      d          cnt
----------- ---------- --------------------
1           2000-01-01 5
2           2000-01-01 1
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот так выходит. Вывожу серии и побед, и поражений, и данные по серии (длина, начало, конец).

Подготовка:

```
declare @t table ( id smallint identity(1,1), person smallint, EventDatetime date, winn smallint);

insert into @t values 
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(2, '2000-01-01', 1);
```

Вот наши исходные данные:

```
id     person EventDatetime winn
------ ------ ------------- ------
1      1      2000-01-01    1
2      1      2000-01-01    1
3      1      2000-01-01    1
4      1      2000-01-01    0
5      1      2000-01-01    0
6      1      2000-01-01    1
7      1      2000-01-01    1
8      1      2000-01-01    1
9      1      2000-01-01    1
10     1      2000-01-01    1
11     1      2000-01-01    0
12     1      2000-01-01    0
13     1      2000-01-01    0
14     1      2000-01-01    0
15     1      2000-01-01    0
16     1      2000-01-01    0
17     2      2000-01-01    1
```

Для каждой строки определяем начало текущей серии (ищем последнюю строку из предыдущих, у которой значение winn не равно текущему)

```
with c_games as(
    select t.id, t.person, t.EventDatetime, t.winn,
        coalesce((select max(w.id) from @t w
                  where w.person = t.person and w.EventDatetime = t.EventDatetime
                        and w.winn <> t.winn and w.id < t.id),0) as max_prev_other_id
    from @t as t
)
```

Получаем:

```
id     person EventDatetime winn   max_prev_other_id
------ ------ ------------- ------ -----------------
1      1      2000-01-01    1      0
2      1      2000-01-01    1      0
3      1      2000-01-01    1      0
4      1      2000-01-01    0      3
5      1      2000-01-01    0      3
6      1      2000-01-01    1      5
7      1      2000-01-01    1      5
8      1      2000-01-01    1      5
9      1      2000-01-01    1      5
10     1      2000-01-01    1      5
11     1      2000-01-01    0      10
12     1      2000-01-01    0      10
13     1      2000-01-01    0      10
14     1      2000-01-01    0      10
15     1      2000-01-01    0      10
16     1      2000-01-01    0      10
17     2      2000-01-01    1      0
```

Теперь группируем по сериям и для каждой считаем начало, конец, длину, и нумеруем их в порядке убывания длины для каждого участника и даты (в итоге первые из них будут нужными нам самыми длинными)

```
, c_series as(
    select g.person, g.EventDatetime, g.winn, count(id) as serial_length, 
        min(id) as first_id, max(id) as last_id,
        row_number() over(partition by g.person, g.EventDatetime, g.winn
                          order by count(id) desc) as num_series
    from c_games g
    group by g.person, g.EventDatetime, g.winn, g.max_prev_other_id
)
```

Результат:

```
person EventDatetime winn   serial_length first_id last_id num_series
------ ------------- ------ ------------- -------- ------- --------------------
1      2000-01-01    1      3             1        3       2
1      2000-01-01    0      2             4        5       2
1      2000-01-01    1      5             6        10      1
1      2000-01-01    0      6             11       16      1
2      2000-01-01    1      1             17       17      1
```

И берем последовательности с номерами, равными 1.

```
select s.person, s.EventDatetime, s.winn, s.serial_length, s.first_id, s.last_id
from c_series s
where s.num_series = 1
order by s.person, s.EventDatetime, s.winn desc
```

Получаем результат:

```
person EventDatetime winn   serial_length first_id last_id
------ ------------- ------ ------------- -------- -------
1      2000-01-01    1      5             6        10
1      2000-01-01    0      6             11       16
2      2000-01-01    1      1             17       17
```

Answer (score 0):

Это называется проблемой пробелов и островов (Gaps and Islands Problem in English).

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (seq INT identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, person INT, EventDatetime DATE, winn SMALLINT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (person, EventDatetime, winn) VALUES
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 1),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(1, '2000-01-01', 0),
(2, '2000-01-01', 1);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT *, SUM(IIF(winn <> ns, 1, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY seq) AS series
    FROM (
        SELECT series.*,
               LAG(winn) OVER (ORDER BY seq) AS ns
        FROM @tbl AS series
    ) q
), rs AS
(
SELECT MIN(cte.person) AS person, series, cnt = MAX(cte.seq) - MIN(cte.seq) + 1
FROM cte
WHERE winn = 1
GROUP BY cte.series
)
SELECT rs.person, MAX(cnt) AS cnt 
FROM rs
GROUP BY rs.person
ORDER BY rs.person;
```

**Результат**

```
+--------+-----+
| person | cnt |
+--------+-----+
|      1 |   5 |
|      2 |   1 |
+--------+-----+
```

Comment: я так понимаю, корректнее таки нумеровать строки, а не id вычитать, которые на практике могут быть непоследовательны?